# Sheva Brachos Seder

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, wedding, sheva-brachos

What does one do if his or her Sheva Brachos comes out on Seder Night do the Kosos become Sheva Brachos and what are all the other Halachic Implications?

Comment: Rabbi Frand Tape # 797 – Sheva Brachos at the Seder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the *hagada* by the author of *K'sav Sofer* (which seems to be called *Seder Lel Hiskadesh Chag*?) the *kos shel b'racha* of *birkas hamazon* should be used for *sheva b'rachos* as well because the *birkas hamazon* catalyzes the *sheva b'rachos* anyway and is therefore not serving a double purpose (which could be problematic).

In addition he brings down a *hakpada* of Rav Ya'akov Emden that the particular cup used for *sheva b'rachos* should be that of the groom in case each person at the table has his own.